# How to custom reset jquery ui buttonset?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, reset

How can I reset radio buttons or checkbox of a jquery ui buttonset made without using "form.reset()", because I want to reset this specific field.

Code is here...: http://jsfiddle.net/tPH57/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the [`refresh`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#method-refresh) method on the button:  http://jsfiddle.net/AAcJ5/1/

From the documentation:

> Refreshes the visual state of the button. Useful for updating button state after the native element's checked or disabled state is changed programatically.